# How and when value for this irq is initialised

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I am going through part of the Linux kernel's source code in `arch/arm/kernel/perf_event.c` and trying to understand how `request_irq` set-up has been made here:

```
static int armpmu_reserve_hardware(struct arm_pmu *armpmu)
 {
    int err;
    struct platform_device *pmu_device = armpmu->plat_device;

    if (!pmu_device)
            return -ENODEV;

    pm_runtime_get_sync(&pmu_device->dev);
    err = armpmu->request_irq(armpmu, armpmu_dispatch_irq);
    if (err) {
            armpmu_release_hardware(armpmu);
            return err;
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Now value of first argument to request_irq should be an integer.Now I could not figured out how is integer value is being initialised.

Also `struct pmu` is given here:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/pmu.h

We have defined PMU representation in kernel device tree file

```
 pmu {
     compatible = "arm,cortex-a15-pmu";
     interrupts = <0 20 0xf01 0 21 0xf01 0 22 0xf01 0 23 0xf01 >;
  };
```

Now, I believe one of the interupt line is driven for 20,21,22,23 but now sure how?

Comment: A function pointer named `foobar()` in a structure does not have to call a global function called `foobar()`;  Replace `foobar()` with `request_irq()`.  You may think that is logical, but it is not enforced by the language and you definitely don't want to switch to C++ if you think this way.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this code](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/3721031#81) request_id need a `struct arm_pmu*`

Comment: Yes mathk,that part I understood but when and how that struct arm_pmu * takes ot valude from??

Comment: Ok but you wrote `Now value of first argument to request_irq should be an integer` ??

Comment: You sentence does not make sens. The first argument of request_irq is not an integer, it is a struct.

Comment: Certainly that is not the same request_irq.